# How to override camera button of Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

For Google Glass app I need to **override** the shortcut **button of camera** in **google glass**.

Let me explain the scenario :
Google glass have shortcut camera button which help to capture image faster. After capturing the image that can be shared via email and other options. For project requirement when application is running I need to make the camera button not accessible by user so that user will not able to capture and send image to anyone else.

How to achieve this options inside the application?

Comment: Shivan right now app is developing using native android SDK.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your application is based on an immersion, have your activity override the `onKeyDown` method and return `true` when the key code is `KEYCODE_CAMERA`. This will cause Android to bypass the built-in camera.